# VBA - Offset of Range Object (a named reference)

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new to VBA and I'm finding it quite difficult to understand the MS VBA documentation.

I am writing a macro to perform some scenario testing on a financial model. I have a named reference called Notional Tenor (integer value) and I want to retrieve the value of the cell (3 + J (previously defined integer value) to the right).

```
Dim Notional_Tenor As Range, Value As Integer
Set Notional_Tenor = Sheets("Scenario & Inputs").Range("Notional_Tenor")
Value = Notional_Tenor.Offset(0, 3 + J).Value2
Debug.Print Value
```

My Debug.Print statement is not showing anything in my immediate box (value should be equal to 18). Is it my code?

Any help much appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Is `J` defined and set?

Comment: Check with the debugger the address of the Range variable `Notional_Tenor`: Is it pointing to the expected address (You could use `Debug.Print Notional_Tenor.address`). Check content of variable `J`: Does it have the expected value?

Comment: While sheet "Scenario & Inputs" active, try to add `Notional_Tenor.Offset(0, 3 + J).select` , step run (F8) in vba editor, then see if the selected cell is correct (has value 18).

Comment: @MG92 Yes it is defined and set

Comment: @FunThomas Yes this helps a lot thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the range "Notional_Tenor" is not a singular cell (for example, a range 3 cells x 5 cells), then this offset will not function properly as it can't return a value for multiple cells.
If it is a singular cell, just reference it directly.
If you are searching through a range to find the reference cell, you can achieve that with something like this:

```
Dim j As Integer
Dim foundRange As Range
Dim searchFor as string
Dim Notional_Tenor As Range
Dim Value As Integer

j = 1
searchFor = "some value"

Set Notional_Tenor = Sheets("Scenario & Inputs").Range("Notional_Tenor")

Set foundRange = Notional_Tenor.Find(What:=searchFor, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Value = foundRange.Offset(0, 3 + j).Value
MsgBox Value
```